# NestJS - is is possible to get the parameter's value within a nest ParamDecorator?

Tags: typescript, nestjs, javascript-decorators

I do have 2 decorators: `@CurrentUser()` and `@MinimumRole(Role.manager)`

- The `@CurrentUser` takes the user from the context and set it to the decorated parameter.
- The `@MinimumRole(Role.manager)` check if the user in the context has the minimum specified role, throw if this is not the case.

The code of the second decorator is as follow:

```
export const MinimumRole = createParamDecorator(
  (minimumRole: Role, executionContext: ExecutionContext) => {

    const user = getCurrentUserFromContext(executionContext);
    assertHasMinimumRole(user.role, minimumRole); // throw if the condition is not met
    return undefined;
  });
```

Now, I would like the `@MinimumRole` to work like a transparent decorator i.e. without changing the decorated value. Because right now if I do so:

`@CurrentUser() @MinimumRole(Role.manager) user: User;` it works (@CurrentUser is last to be called and therefore last to return the value)

while

`@MinimumRole(Role.manager) @CurrentUser() user: User`; will set `undefined` to the decorated value (as my decorator returns undefined) and therefore override the users value.

I do see 2 solutions but I need some help:

1. Either there is a way to get the target's value in the `createParamDecorator`, in which case I would be able to return this value.
2. Moving the decorator so that it decorates the whole method instead of a parameter's only. But I would then need to know how to get the context from a method decorator in nestjs.

Comment: What should happen if `checkHasMinimumRole()` were to return `false` (assuming it returns anything)? It sounds like a decorator may not be the right use case here

Comment: I need to clarify that the `checkHasMinimumRole` is an assert, I will correct the question renaming is properly

Comment: But what's supposed to happen if that requirement is not met? Should an error be thrown? Cause if so, a guard might be a better place to do this

Comment: a guard on the resolver might be the cleanest solution (despite it will be on the resolver itself) https://github.com/nestjs/graphql/issues/295

Comment: I need however to check if the guard is called after the interceptor as the context is built within an interceptor (it should be the case btw)

Comment: Guards are called before interceptors. This is part of the [request lifecycle](https://docs.nestjs.com/faq/request-lifecycle)